# Import android library (aab) R values

Tags: android, android-library

I'm trying to implement an android library which will embedded some assets. 
I successfully implement the library, and I have generated an `.aab` (but I can't change the name nor define a version). 
In this `.aab` file, I have `/res/drawables/{all_assets}` 
It seems I have integrate my `.aab` successfully in another project (by putting the `.aab` inside `libs` and `build.gradle.kts`) 
But, when I try to use assets, assets aren't found. I mean, the `import` part is underline by red and the asset name is red too. But, when I compile the app, assets are found and display correctly. 
Is there a way to avoid these underline by red? 
Thanks!

I've try to clear my project, to invalidate cache,...

Comment: I have no idea what the best practice is in this case, but if the goal of the library is to share assets I would do a get function for each assets...